# passing an array to kernel that is same for all work items

Tags: c++, opencl

I have Intel i7-8700K processor with UHD 630 in-built graphic card. I am using opencl 2.0 C++ extension (cl2.hpp).

I have a kernel string

```
    std::string kernel1{
    "kernel void frustumCheck(global float3 *contPoints, global const float3 *camPoints, global const float3 *camDirection, global bool *outMatG, float3 camParams, int numControl){"
    "  float3 worldUp = (float3)(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);"
    "  int iterId = get_global_id(0);"
    "  float3 camRight = normalize(cross(camDirection[iterId], worldUp));"
    "  float3 camUp = normalize(cross(camRight, camDirection[iterId]));"
    // Field of view parameter calculation
    "  float3 farCenter = camPoints[iterId] + camDirection[iterId]*camParams.z;"
    "  float3 far_tl = farCenter + camUp*camParams.y - camRight*camParams.x;"
    "  float3 far_bl = far_tl - camUp*2*camParams.y;"
    "  float3 far_br = far_bl + camRight*2*camParams.x;"
    "  float3 far_tr = far_br + camUp*2*camParams.y;"
    "  bool check = 0;"
    "  for(int i = 0; i < numControl; i++){"
    //"    printf(\" do processing here \");"
    //"    printf(\" can i access as contPoints[i] ? \");"
    "  }"
    //"printf(\"Processed id %d \\n\\n\", iterId);"
"}"};
```

Where camPoints and camDirection are two input arrays of same dimensions. I want to pass the entire array contPoints (dim = numControl) and each work item in the camPoints array will use the entire contPoints array (in the for loop). I am not able to understand how to pass this array so that the entire array is available for each work item. outMatG is an output 2D array.

The following shows the initialization of vectors and the kernel program.

```
    // SVM allocations for input variables
cl::SVMAllocator<int, cl::SVMTraitCoarse<>> svmAlloc;
qDebug() << "Max alloc size: " << svmAlloc.max_size() << " bytes\n";
std::vector<cl_float3, cl::SVMAllocator<int, cl::SVMTraitCoarse<>>> contPoints(svmAlloc);
contPoints.resize(numControl);
std::vector<cl_float3, cl::SVMAllocator<int, cl::SVMTraitCoarse<>>> camPoints(svmAlloc);
std::vector<cl_float3, cl::SVMAllocator<int, cl::SVMTraitCoarse<>>> camDirection(svmAlloc);

// SVM allocation for output matrix g
std::vector<std::vector<bool>, cl::SVMAllocator<int, cl::SVMTraitCoarse<>>> outMatG(svmAlloc);

auto frustumCheckKernel =
        cl::KernelFunctor<
            std::vector<cl_float3, cl::SVMAllocator<int, cl::SVMTraitCoarse<>>>&,
            std::vector<cl_float3, cl::SVMAllocator<int, cl::SVMTraitCoarse<>>>&,
            std::vector<cl_float3, cl::SVMAllocator<int, cl::SVMTraitCoarse<>>>&,
            std::vector<std::vector<bool> , cl::SVMAllocator<int, cl::SVMTraitCoarse<>>>&,
            cl_float3,
            int
        >(camProgram, "frustumCheck");
```

And I call the kernel function as

```
cl_int error;
    frustumCheckKernel(
                cl::EnqueueArgs(blockSize),
                contPoints,
                camPoints,
                camDirection,
                outMatG,
                camParams,
                numControl,
                error
                );
```

Where blockSize refers to batches of 1000 vector elements that I process inside a while loop.

I was following the example at https://github.com/KhronosGroup/OpenCL-CLHPP/blob/master/examples/src/trivialCL2.cpp. Is this a correct way to do this? I tried to pass it as a std::vector of float3  but it throws an error saying data type not specified.

I am new to opencl and any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Anirudh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some thinking, i realized that my basics on how passing arrays to kernels were not clear. I solved the problem by operating two separate kernels as my data is multidimensional. Moreover, the second problem is dependent on the results from the first one, so, two separate kernels did the job. This closes the question.

Thanks.